# How can I get Mapbox to route between points instead of drawing straight lines?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am using Mapbox to draw the polyline between the points on map, but the line is messy it is not printing as per the map routes can someone please help me with this or please suggest some alternatives.

[image]

```
 var myMap = L.mapbox.map('map')
.setView([34.2445899, -119.1842238], 13)
.addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'));
var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
var refreshRealTime;
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(myMap); 

 

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        let body = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        let coords_line = [];
        let stopArr = [];
        for(let i=0; i<body.length; i++){
            let data = body[i];
            let stop =  data.stop;
            
            if(!stopArr.includes(stop.name)){
                coords_line.push([stop.lat, stop.lon ]);
                let marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(stop.lat, stop.lon), {
                    icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'bus', 'marker-color': '0044FF', 'description':'<div><p><b>Cpanacity: </b></div>'}),
                    title: stop.name
                });
                marker.bindPopup(stop.name);
                markers.addLayer(marker);
                stopArr.push(stop.name);
            }
        
        }
        myMap.addLayer(markers);
        if(coords_line.length > 0){
            myMap.setView(coords_line[0], 13);
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                let routeId= $("#route").val();
                let routecolor = routeObj[routeId].color;
                
                polyline = L.polyline(coords_line, {color: routecolor}).addTo(myMap);
                
                
             }, 1000);
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: There is not enough detail here to assist you with your messy line problem.

Comment: Hi @Wyck what details you need ?

Comment: Are you attempting to use the [directions API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/directions)?

Comment: @isherwood I am not using any direction API, I just want it should work like google map just like http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5om01gq3/2/

Answer (score 0):

After debugging I found the solution, in that first we need to call the direction API based on given points

```
 $.get('https://api.mapbox.com/matching/v5/mapbox/driving/' + qry + '?geometries=geojson&steps=true&access_token='+token, 
        function( data ) {
        // var coords = polyline.decode(data.routes[0].geometry);
        var coords = data.matchings[0].geometry.coordinates;
        let coords_line = [];
        for(let i=0; i<coords.length; i++){
            coords_line.push([coords[i][1],coords[i][0]]);
        }
        polyline = L.polyline(coords_line, {color: '<?= $color ?>'}).addTo(myMap)
```

**then we should print the polylines**

**Full Code is here**

```
    var myMap = L.mapbox.map('map')
.setView([34.2445899, -119.1842238], 13)
.addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'));
var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
var refreshRealTime;
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(myMap); 

 

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        let body = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        let coords_line = [];
        let stopArr = [];
        let qry = [];
        for(let i=0; i<body.length; i++){
            let data = body[i];
            let stop =  data.stop;
            
            if(!stopArr.includes(stop.name)){
                coords_line.push([stop.lat, stop.lon ]);
                qry.push(stop.lon+','+stop.lat);
                let marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(stop.lat, stop.lon), {
                    icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'bus', 'marker-color': '0044FF', 'description':'<div><p><b>Cpanacity: </b></div>'}),
                    title: stop.name
                });
                marker.bindPopup(stop.name);
                markers.addLayer(marker);
                stopArr.push(stop.name);
            }
        
        }
        myMap.addLayer(markers);
        if(coords_line.length > 0){
            myMap.setView(coords_line[0], 13);
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                let routeId= $("#route").val();
                let routecolor = routeObj[routeId].color;
                
                calculateRoute(qry.join(";"));
                
                
             }, 1000);
        }
      }
    };

    function calculateRoute(qry) {
          $.get('https://api.mapbox.com/matching/v5/mapbox/driving/' + qry + '?geometries=geojson&steps=true&access_token='+token, 
            function( data ) {
            // var coords = polyline.decode(data.routes[0].geometry);
            var coords = data.matchings[0].geometry.coordinates;
            let coords_line = [];
            for(let i=0; i<coords.length; i++){
                coords_line.push([coords[i][1],coords[i][0]]);
            }
            polyline = L.polyline(coords_line, {color: '<?= $color ?>'}).addTo(myMap)
                // addRoute(coords);
            // var line = L.polyline(coords).addTo(myMap);

          });  
        }
```

[map view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6ymf.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious you are not using the directions API that helps to display the routing route here is a general setup you need to implement according to your code:

```
const fetchRoute = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/${userLocation[0]},${userLocation[1]};${selectedLocation[0]},${selectedLocation[1]}?access_token=${accessToken}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      
      const routeGeometry = data.routes[0].geometry;
      const decodedCoordinates = polyline.decode(routeGeometry);
      setRouteCoordinates(decodedCoordinates);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching or processing route:', error);
    }
  }
};
```